# define member function template that receive pointer to other class member function add apply the function

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` which has a member variable `vector<B>`.  I want to define a function template named `DoToAll(funcPtr)` that will iterate on all the vector and apply the function.

```
class A 
{
vector<B> v;
template <?????>
void DoToAll(f);
loop on v and apply the member function f;
}

class B{
void f1();
void f2();
.
.
.
}
```

How do I write `DoToAll`?

Comment: So you want to rewrite `std::for_each` ?

Answer (score 4):

Do you insist that the argument must be a function pointer? Otherwise, it could be just

```
template <class F>
void DoToAll(F f) {
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
}
```

That works for every `f` st. `f(x)`, where `x` is an element of the vector, is valid. That means function pointers and functors such as `std::function` and `std::bind` are all right. Unfortunately, that doesn't include member function pointers, since you call them `x->*f()`, not `f()`. But that is possible to overcome, too, by wrapping the member function pointer into a functor that would correctly forward the call. The standard already provides such adapters, the one appropriate for you would be [`mem_fun_ref_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun_ref/). You could add an overload of `DoToAll` that takes function pointers:

```
template <class This, class Ret>
void DoToAll(Ret (*This::f)()) {
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(f));
}
```

Comment: thanks! i am new to c++ ,can for_each work on member function?!

Answer (score 0):

If you use only functions here, you don't need templates at all.

```
void DoToAll(void (*f)(B&)) { /*...*/ }
```

So you can write something like this

```
void Change(const B& what)
{
    what.ChangeSomething();
}
//...
a.DoToAll(Change) // or a.DoToAll(&Change)
```